# MAAS Error on pxe image importing time

Tags: maas, pxe

I have install *maas* on one of our server. It getting error on *pxe image import time*.

```
Fri, 15 Nov 2013 18:50:52 +0530: finished. wrote to /var/lib/maas/ephemeral/raring/ephemeral/amd64/20131015/dist-root.tar.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/maas-import-ephemerals", line 26, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/provisioningserver/import_images/ephemerals_script.py", line 428, in main
    target.sync(source, args.path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplestreams/mirrors/__init__.py", line 85, in sync
    return self.sync_index(reader, path, data, content)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplestreams/mirrors/__init__.py", line 230, in sync_index
    self.sync(reader, path=epath)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplestreams/mirrors/__init__.py", line 83, in sync
    return self.sync_products(reader, path, data, content)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplestreams/mirrors/__init__.py", line 308, in sync_products
    self.insert_item(item, src, target, pgree, ipath_cs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/provisioningserver/import_images/ephemerals_script.py", line 247, in insert_item
    data, src, target, pedigree, contentsource)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplestreams/mirrors/__init__.py", line 401, in insert_item
    size=data.get('size'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplestreams/objectstores/__init__.py", line 141, in insert
    os.unlink(partfile)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/lib/maas/ephemeral/.simplestreams/saucy/release-20131017/saucy-daily-maas-i386.tar.gz.part


jagan@ubuntu:~$ ls -lh /var/lib/maas/ephemeral/.simplestreams/saucy/release-20131017/saucy-daily-maas-amd64.tar.gz 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 316M Nov 15 17:35 /var/lib/maas/ephemeral/.simplestreams/saucy/release-20131017/saucy-daily-maas-amd64.tar.gz
```

How to fix this problem ?

Comment: You say this happens every time. Do you mean every time you run the import-pxe-files command or are you reinstalling and retrying? (If you are reinstalling anyway, I would recommend trying the Saucy instead of Raring version.)

Comment: I have the same problem: Ubuntu Server 13.10 installed with MAAS directly from CD-ROM.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, just rebooted the server and ran the command:

```
sudo maas-import-pxe-files
```

and, problem solved.